# How to check my matrix if its divisible by 12

Tags: matlab, division

im new to matlab and i've run into a slight problem. I want to check my matrix that generated random number if they are divisible by 12. Then i want to list number of digit divisible by 12 and the total sum of those.

```
clc
clear
format compact
a=4 
b=0 
N=50+a
R=randi([100+a,159+b], 1, N) % generate random no. from 100+a to 159 on a matrix 1xN
s1=0
N1=0
for i = 1
    for j= 1:N
        if rem(R,12)==0
            N1=N1+1;
            s1=s1+R(i,j);
        else
            N1=N1+0;
            s1=s1+0;
        end
    end
end
numberof1=N1
sum1=s1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because your are calling `rem(R, 12)` (remainder of *all* elements) as opposed to the remainder of the *specific element* (`rem(R(i,j), 12)`).

The better approach though would be to remove the `for` loop and generate a logical matrix the size of `R` that is `true` when that number is divisible by 12 and `false` otherwise by passing the entire matrix to `rem`.

```
is_divisible_by_12 = rem(R, 12) == 0;
```

Then we can use this to compute the sum of these by using this logical array as an index into `R`

```
subset = R(is_divisible_by_12);

number = numel(subset);
s1 = sum(subset);
```